# MessageSource equivalent in Django?

Tags: java, python, django, string, spring

I come from a Java/Spring background and I've just recently moved to Python/Django. I'm working on a new project from scratch with Django. I was wondering how Django handles common String messages. Is there one single common file that can be called in a resources folder? For example, in Spring, we have a MessageSource is a key/value pair properties file that is global to most of the app. Is there something similar in Django? If so, how does it work for the normal app side and the unit tests side?

Comment: You can create a simple module that you can import that have some dictionary with key/values you want to share across the app.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look over [Django's messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/).

Also, you can use key-value pairs in Python, with dicts:

```
# Upper case because it is constant

LOGIN_ERRROS = {
    'login_error_message': 'message here',
    ...
}
```

You could put this in a file, you can even name it `message_source.py`, inside you app and import it when you need it:

For example, in your view:

```
# views.py

...
from myapp.message_source import LOGIN_ERRORS
```

Answer (score 0):

Django uses the standard `gettext` + `.po` files for internationalization/translation. Check out the Translation docs for all the steps needed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/